# undefined method `cookie_expiration' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, clearance

getting a no method error while using clearance for authentication, i was trying to create a user using sign_up 
clearance (0.11.1)
rails 3.0.7
ruby 1.8.7
on Windows XP.

```
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing'
clearance (0.11.1) lib/clearance/authentication.rb:51:in `sign_in'
clearance (0.11.1) app/controllers/clearance/users_controller.rb:15:in `create'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:150:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:11:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:443:in `_run__901813995__process_action__524098549__callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:410:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `send'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:94:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:52:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:119:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:41:in `process'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:138:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:178:in `action'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:27:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:148:in `call'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:93:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:75:in `optimized_each'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/code_generation.rb:92:in `recognize'
rack-mount (0.6.14) lib/rack/mount/route_set.rb:139:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:493:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:182:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:149:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:302:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:32:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:28:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:12:in `cache'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:31:in `call'
activerecord (3.0.7) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:354:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:46:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run_call_callbacks'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:44:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:107:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.0.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (3.0.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:30:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:168:in `call'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:52:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
rack (1.2.3) lib/rack/server.rb:217:in `start'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:30
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
railties (3.0.7) lib/rails/commands.rb:27
script/rails:6:in `require'
script/rails:6
```

EDIT: Code added:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Clearance::Authentication
  protect_from_forgery
end
```

model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Clearance::User
end
```

HTML erb

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>

<%= form_for :session, :url => session_path do |form| %>
  <div class="text_field">
    <%= form.label :email %>
    <%= form.text_field :email, :type => "email" %>
  </div>
  <div class="text_field">
    <%= form.label :password %>
    <%= form.password_field :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="submit_field">
    <%= form.submit "Sign in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<ul>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Sign up", sign_up_path %>
  </li>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Forgot password?", new_password_path %>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you paste your code?

Comment: generate app using rails new, and installed gem clearance, generated views using rails g clearance:install and rails g clearance:views, plain skeleton code.

Comment: take a look at this issue: http://groups.google.com/group/thoughtbot-clearance/browse_thread/thread/a10cfb543a6526a5/051ce913880fc40f

Comment: that didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed and re-installed clearance gem and gave a server-restart.

Not seeing the error anymore.